# Docker wait untill a service is completely ready

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm dockerizing my existing **Django** application.

I have an `entrypoint.sh` script which run as entrypoint by the **Dockerfile**

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/scripts/docker/entrypoint.sh"]
```

It's content contains script to run migration when environment variable is set to migrate

```
#!/bin/sh
#set -e

# Run the command and exit with the custom message when the comamnd fails to run
safeRunCommand() {
  cmnd="$*"
  echo cmnd="$cmnd"
  eval "$cmnd"
  ret_code=$?
  if [ $ret_code != 0 ]; then
    printf "Error : [code: %d] when executing command: '$cmnd'\n" $ret_code
    exit $ret_code
  else
    echo "Command run successfully: $cmnd"
  fi
}

runDjangoMigrate() {
  echo "Migrating database"
  cmnd="python manage.py migrate --noinput"
  safeRunCommand "$cmnd"
  echo "Done: Migrating database"
}

# Run Django migrate command.
# The command is run only when environment variable `DJANGO_MANAGE_MIGRATE` is set to `on`.
if [ "x$DJANGO_MANAGE_MIGRATE" = 'xon' ] && [ ! "x$DEPLOYMENT_MODE" = 'xproduction' ]; then
  runDjangoMigrate
fi

# Accept other commands
exec "$@"
```

Now, in the `docker-compose` file, I have the services like

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: 'qcg7_db_mysql'
    restart: always

  web:
    build: .
    command: ["./wait_for_it.sh", "database:3306", "--", "./docker_start.sh"]
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      DJANGO_MANAGE_MIGRATE: 'on'
```

But when I build the image using

```
docker-compose up --build
```

It fails to run the migration command from entrypoint script with error

```
(2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'database' (115)")
```

This is due to the fact that the database server has not still started.

**How can I make `web` service to wait untill the `database` service is completely started and is ready to accept connections?**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not a native way in Docker to wait for the database service to be ready before Django web app attempts to connect.  Depends_on will only ensure that the web app is started after the database container is launched.

Because of this limitation you will need to solve this problem in how your container runs.  The easiest solution is to modify the entrypoint.sh to sleep for 10-30 seconds so that your database has time to initialize before executing any additional commands.  [This official MySQL entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.6/docker-entrypoint.sh) shows an example of how to block until the database is ready.

Comment: You can always `nc database 3306` in a `while` (with a lower `sleep 1`) and `break` when the db is up.

Comment: Yes.  Either works.  The key point is the entrypoint.sh needs to do some sort of checking or blocking to wait for the database to be ready.